# Conway's subprime Fibonacci sequences

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, open-problems, integer-sequences

I want to be certain I have the latest information on
[Conway's subprime Fibonacci sequences](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5099),
arXiv-posted a year ago; I am referencing the status in
a review. 
To wit, starting with $(0,1)$:<sup>1</sup>
$$
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 11, 17, 14, 31, 15, 23, 19, \ldots
$$

> [Richard K. Guy, Tanya Khovanova, Julian Salazar](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5099):
>   
>   "however, it seems more likely here than in the $3x + 1$
>   problem that sequences do not increase indefinitely. Here is an informal argument that
>   supports such a conjecture,"

***$\color{Red}{Q}$***: Has it been established that *some* sequence increases indefinitely?
Or no sequence, regardless of starting conditions, does not?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>"Start with the Fibonacci sequence 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, . . . , but before you write down a composite
term, divide it by its least prime factor so that this next term is not 8, but rather 8/2 = 4."</sup>

Comment: Also published as Conway’s Subprime Fibonacci Sequences, Richard K. Guy, Tanya Khovanova and Julian Salazar,
Mathematics Magazine Vol. 87, No. 5 (December 2014), pp. 323-337.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat different (but related) sequence has been [analyzed satisfactorily.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04807) Quite recently, too (*A Note on Prime Fibonacci Sequences*, Jeremy Alm, Taylor Herald
(Submitted on 17 Jul 2015)).